# How to pass a variable taken from the selected item of this listbox? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox and I need a way to pass the selected item to a UserControl.
How can I do it?

```
<Grid >
  <ListBox Name="lbPersonaggi"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single"><!--SelectionChanged="lbPersonaggi_SelectionChanged"-->
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Name="TBPG" Text="{Binding Personaggio}" MouseUp="ClickPG" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>




</Grid>
```

Comment: It would be better if you show us what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your ListBox Definition header:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=YourPropertyWhereYouWantToStoreTheValue, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

And then Re-use this property in your second Control.

I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set the selected item as DataContext for another UserControl you write something like this

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding lbPersonaggi.SelectedItem}" />
```

You don't need a property in your viewmodel to store the selected item.

Comment: Only if the UserControl is in the same XAML file.